# Aligning views div to right

Tags: html, css

I want to align the `views` div to the right side of the `question-card` block and left of the `ago div.

[Layout Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lcaK.png)

```css
.question-card{
  margin-left: 20px;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
   width: 60%;
}
.circled-dp{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 50%;
}
.profile{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.ago{
margin-left: auto;
}
.views{
  float: right!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="post.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="question-card">
<img class="img" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="profile">
<img class="circled-dp" src="https://drslash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-Studio.png">
<p class="profile-name">Someone</p>
<div class="views"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>100</span></div>
<p class="ago">17-nov-2016</p>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.
`

Comment: so you want to put 100 in left and 17 nov in right, right?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: What do u want ? @JimFahad    . I want to align the views block to the right ... By which it will be positioned at left of the ago block   .. tbh my english is not good

Comment: @IamNOOB so it will be lilke Someone 100 and in right 17nov2016, right?

Comment: yeahhhhh @Leothelion

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/o9meut5c/

Comment: Nooo I want the '100' to align at the left side of time.. But not the left side of card.. I suck at explaining. Let me draw a simple diagram

Comment: added...........@Leothelion

Comment: @IamNOOB check this one https://jsfiddle.net/o9meut5c/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have div with css: `display: flex;` so you can use these properties in appropriate places:

`justify-content: space-between;`

`align-items: center;`

```css
.question-card{
  margin-left: 20px;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
   width: 60%;
}
.circled-dp{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 50%;
}
.profile{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
}
.ago{
margin-left: auto;
}
.views{
}
span{
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="post.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="question-card">
<img class="img" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="profile">
<div class="flex">
  <img class="circled-dp" src="https://drslash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-Studio.png">
  <p class="profile-name">Someone</p>
</div>
<div class="views flex">
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>100</span>
<p class="ago">17-nov-2016</p>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use full-fledged **CSS Flexbox**. Structure your `.profile` a little bit differently.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.question-card{
  margin-left: 20px;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
   width: 80%;
}
.circled-dp{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 50%;
}
.profile{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.ago{
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.element {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-name {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-card">
<img class="img" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="profile">
  <div class="element left">
  <img class="circled-dp" src="https://drslash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-Studio.png">
  <p class="profile-name">Someone</p>
  </div>
<div class="element right">
  <div class="views"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>100</span></div>
  <p class="ago">17-nov-2016</p>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `postion:relative` for the  `profile` class , so it's content (which have `position:absolute` ) can be placed as you want inside this last :

```css
.question-card{
  margin-left: 20px;
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   transition: 0.3s;
   width: 60%;
}
.circled-dp{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 50%;
}
.profile{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  position:relative;  /*position added */
}
.ago{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.views{
  position:absolute; /* added*/
  right:100px;
  padding-top:16px; /* added */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="post.css">
  <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="question-card">
<img class="img" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="profile">
<img class="circled-dp" src="https://drslash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-Studio.png">
<p class="profile-name">Someone</p>
<div class="views"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>100</span></div>
<p class="ago">17-nov-2016</p>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the layout on question :(

Comment: @IamNOOB , Okey sorry , At first ,I had misunderstood the question so after it was been edited , I've edit my answer !

Answer (score 1):

FOR UPDATE QUESTION ::

Just change some CS Style:
[LIVE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/o9meut5c/2/)

```
.profile{
     padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
p.profile-name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.views {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 92px;
}
.views p {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.question-card{
  margin-left: 20px;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
   width: 60%;
}
.circled-dp {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 50%;
}
.profile{
     padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.ago {
  float:right;
margin-left: auto;
}
p.profile-name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.views {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 92px;
}
.views p {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="question-card">
<img class="img" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="profile">
<img class="circled-dp" src="https://drslash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-Studio.png">
<p class="profile-name">Someone</p>
<div class="views"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>100</p></div>    
<p class="ago">17-nov-2016</p>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: See the layout on question :(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```css
.question-card{
  margin-left: 20px;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
   width: 60%;
}
.circled-dp{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 50%;
}
.profile{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.ago {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
 }
.views {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: end;
   margin-top: 6px;
   width: 100%;
 }
.view{
  float: left;
}
.profile-name {
   margin-left: 3px;
   margin-top: 7px;
}
 .view span {
   margin-right: 15px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="post.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="question-card">
<img class="img" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="profile">
<img class="circled-dp" src="https://drslash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-Studio.png">
<p class="profile-name">Someone</p>
<div class="views">
<div class="view"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>100</span></div>
<p class="ago">17-nov-2016</p>
</div>

</div>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the layout on question :(